# Why is HttpCacheMiddleware disabled in scrapyd?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

Why does HttpCachedMiddleware need scrapy.cfg and how do I work around this issue?

I use `scrapyd-deploy` to build the egg, and deploy project to scrapyd.

When the job is run, I see from the log output that the HttpCacheMiddleware is disabled because scrapy.cfg is not found.

> 2014-06-08 18:55:51-0700 [scrapy] WARNING: Disabled HttpCacheMiddleware: Unable to find scrapy.cfg file to infer project data dir

I check the egg file and scrapy.cfg is indeed not there because the egg file only consists of the files in the project directory.  I could be wrong, but I think the egg is built correctly.

```
foo/
 |- project/
 |      |- __init__.py
 |      |- settings.py
 |      |- spiders/
 |            |- ...
 |- scrapy.cfg
```

Digging into the [code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/fb770852e87d97196e31f27c33ee8eee89aecc27/scrapy/middleware.py#L28-L41) more, I think one of the three if-condition is failing somehow in MiddlewareManager.

```
        try:
            mwcls = load_object(clspath)
            if crawler and hasattr(mwcls, 'from_crawler'):
                mw = mwcls.from_crawler(crawler)
            elif hasattr(mwcls, 'from_settings'):
                mw = mwcls.from_settings(settings)
            else:
                mw = mwcls()
            middlewares.append(mw)
        except NotConfigured, e:
            if e.args:
                clsname = clspath.split('.')[-1]
                log.msg(format="Disabled %(clsname)s: %(eargs)s",
                        level=log.WARNING, clsname=clsname, eargs=e.args[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place an empty `scrapy.cfg` under your working directory.

As the [source code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/utils/project.py#L26) shows, `project_data_dir` will try to find the closest `scrapy.cfg` and use it to infer the project data dir.

Comment: I think even emptying ```scrapy.cfg``` wounld not solve the problem.  When the spider is deployed as egg to scrapyd, the file ```scrapy.cfg``` is actually not included.  I think the code would just disable the middleware when the location is indeterministic.  The only way to make it work is to hard code a absolute path.

Comment: @Sam The empty `scrapy.cfg` is to be placed under where you run `scrapyd`. Yes, the `scrapy.cfg` in the scrapy project root is not included in the egg, but in runtime, `scrapyd` will looking for `scrapy.cfg` from the working directory first. If not presented, it will try other places. Tested on scrapy `0.22.2` and scrapyd `1.0.1`.

Comment: Ah, I see you what you meant now by having an empty ```scrapy.cfg``` just to let scrapyd to determine the location.  Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Answeror What do you mean by 'your working directory'? Does it make a difference what directory you are in when you start `scrapyd`?